# BlockingCollection not Performing as Expected

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

I have a method that invokes a passed `Func` on a background thread called `TaskSpin`. This does one method at a time based on the site clicked in a `DataGridView` (DGV), and it can SHOULD ONLY do one at a time. So I click on a site (a button cell in the DGV) and it run the method on that site. Now I have many sites and do not want to click and wait hundreds of times, instead I want to batch process all the sites contained in the DGV. I cannot use a straight loop to run these, i.e.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DGV)
    TaskSpin(SomeMethod, SomeParameterArray);
```

as this returns to caller almost immediately, and will begin running the following site which is not good as they use shared files. So I need a way to queue the sites up to be execute one-by-one. I have decided to use a `ConncurrentCollection - BlockingCollection`, but I am stuck. In some button click event I have

```
BlockingCollection<Action<object[]>> taskQueue = 
    new BlockingCollection<Action<object[]>>();
List<object[]> paramQueue = new List<object[]>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridViewDrg.Rows) 
{
    paramQueue.Add(DrgDataRowInfo(row.Index));
    Action<object[]> action = new Action<object[]>(AsyncMethod);
    taskQueue.Add(action);
}
int i = 0;
foreach (Action<object[]> action in taskQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    action(paramQueue[i]);
```

where `AsyncMethod` launched a set method on the background thread using TPL.

```
private void AsyncMethod(object[] siteInfo)
{
    TaskSpin(BuildDataForSite, siteInfo);
}
```

My expectation is that this would run each `Action<object[]>` one after the other. But this is just freezing my application. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

**Edit. TaskSpin**

```
public TaskSpin(Func asyncMethod, object[] methodParameters)
{
    ...
    asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => 
        asyncMethod(uiScheduler, methodParameters));

    asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        ...
        // Finish the processing update UI etc.
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is kind of long, but the shortened version I will add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
foreach (Action<object[]> action in taskQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    action(paramQueue[i]);
```

is running on your UI thread, thus causing the block.

Your requirement seems to be that you want to process a list of things, one at a time, on a non-UI thread.  To accomplish that with your current code and minimal modification, you can move your *foreach* above into a separate thread, e.g. by creating a single Task that runs the *foreach*.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    foreach (Action<object[]> action in taskQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        action(paramQueue[i]);
});
```

Comment: The only thing is that the action in the foreach loop should be a method that is spinning off its own thread anyway, so here it should not matter if I use the UI thread or not... Thanks for your time.

Comment: And the `BlockingCollection` could a simple `BlockingCollection<object[]>`, since he's always invoking the same method (`TaskSpin`).

Comment: @Kilercam: No, `Action<T>` is essentially a collection of function pointers.  Your *foreach* just calls each function through its pointer from the UI thread.

Comment: @EricJ: Unless inside TaskSpin is where the asynchronous call begins, otherwise, yes, it is synchronous.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: The update shows that indeed that is the case, though there's not enough code shown to understand why TaskSpin might block after all.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am late

My solution is to use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (Action<object[]> action in taskQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        action(paramQueue[i]);
});
```

I am posting this answer based on this [article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

I also was using `Task.Factory.StartNew` but then it sometimes ran on my UI thread causing my app to hang. `Task.Run` solved my issue.